# Infinite compilation with templates

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, recursion

This question is just out of curiosity. In recursive templates if we forget to put one particular specialization, then compiler will do large number of iterations and then stop at sometime and gives error such as,

```
error: incomplete type ‘X<-0x000000000000001ca>’ used in nested name specifier
```

In certain cases, the compilation goes **infinite**. For example, see the below code (just for illustration; compiled with gcc 4.4.1):

```
template<int I>
struct Infinite
{
  enum { value = (I & 0x1)? Infinite<I+1>::value : Infinite<I-1>::value };
};

int main ()
{
  int i = Infinite<1>::value;
}
```

Should not be compiler smart enough to stop at some time ?

**Edit**:  The compilation error shown above is for other code. For the sample code, compilation never stops (however, I get to see such errors in between)

Comment: This does terminate in g++ 4.8.4 at least... `main.cpp:4:27: error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum) instantiating ‘struct Infinite<-899>’`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the compiler to recognise that it will never stop iterating. Besides just stopping after a fixed number of nesting types, what you want is provably impossible: If I see it correctly you can express any [turing-machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) in this fashion (at least the templates in `D` are turing complete).

So if you can build a compiler that recognises that it will nest types forever before actually trying to, you decide the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) which is undecidable for turing-machines.

However, I could very well be mistaken that you can put any computation in the parameter-list (but simulating a register-machine appears to be possible, as we can encode all registers in a separate integer template parameter (yes, `int` is finite, but quite large, which makes it practically unbounded)).

Answer (score 7):

Getting the parser into an infinite loop using template is not new.

```
// Stresses the compiler infinitely
// from: http://www.fefe.de/c++/c%2b%2b-talk.pdf
template<class T> struct Loop { Loop<T*> operator->(); };
Loop<int> i, j = i->hooray;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Should not be compiler smart enough to stop at some time ?

How do you define the phrase *"at some time"*? How would the compiler know **your** definition of *"at some time"*? How would it know when it must stop if you don't tell it *explicitly*? You've to tell it first by defining specialization(s) of the non-stopping class template (what you've written is non-stopping class template).

In your case, you must have two specializations of the class template, one in each directions (increasing, and decreasing). Something like this:

```
template<>
struct Infinite<100> //this is to stop template with <I+1> argument
{
  enum { value = 678678 }; //see, it doesn't use Infinite<> any further!
};

template<>
struct Infinite<-100> //this is to stop template with <I-1> argument
{
  enum { value = -67878 }; //see, it too doesn't use Infinite<> any further!
};
```

Comment: @Nawaz, actually the question is in more compilation perspective. Why should not compilation stop at sometime, when it know that the compilation going infinite.

Comment: @iammilind: How would it know? Also, At what point should it stop?

Comment: @iammilind: "Why should not compilation stop at sometime, when it know that the compilation going infinite." - It did stop. In your case, it stopped when it gave you the compile error.

Comment: @iammilind: "Know that the compilation going infinite"? In general case "knowing" that the compilation is going to be infinite is an extremely difficult (or even unsolvable) task. The compiler is not required to concern itself with such matters. It is a QoUI issue: if the compiler wishes to spend its efforts to catch such situations, it can. But nobody is requiring it to.

Comment: On top of that, it is very unlikely that the compilation goes infinite in your case. It simply takes a very long time. In any case it will probably either abort eventually, or bottom-out eventually due to wrap-around on overflow. You simply didn't wait long enough.

Comment: @Nawaz, first i haven't downvoted your answer :). 2nd if you take the example of factorial, compiler does stop if you dont specialize Fact<1>. should not it happen in this case also.

Comment: @iammilind: What factorial example are we talking about? The way you implement non-infinite recursion with templates is to define a specialization of the general template that doesn't instantiate itself. For example, [this `Factorial<>` example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming#Using_template_metaprogramming) has both the general template that does the actual recursion and a specialzed template that implements the base case.

Comment: @iammilind: No. It doesn't. Even factorial needs *specialization*. Without it, it cannot stop!

Comment: @In silico @Nawaz, http://www.ideone.com/FU0Au .. the compilation stops after sometime

Comment: @iammilind: So what's your point? I already know that it has to stop because we don't have machines with infinte amount of memory. If we had such machines, then the recursion will go on forever unless the inputs satisfy some kind of a base case.

Comment: @In silico, exactly that's my point. that the above test code doesn't stop compilation. It goes on and on

Comment: @iammilind: Yes that stops BY GIVING COMPILATION ERROR (scroll down and see the ERROR). Its not a normal stop in the sense all of us are talking about here. Also, such stop by giving error would also happen in your code "at some time" , only you've to wait long enough.

Comment: @iammilind: Not "maybe". It IS true (I guarantee :P). You just have to wait long enough. Maybe, 20 mins, 30 mins, 1 hr or 2 hr or even more!

Comment: @Nawaz, true. anyways +1 for the efforts.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does what you ask it do do. You asked it to engage into infinite recursion - it did exactly that. If you want it to "stop at some time", you have to ask it to stop at "some time" and tell it what specific "some time" you mean exactly.

Template recursion is not different from any other recursion in C++ program: it is your responsibility to specify where the recursion bottoms-out.

Comment: In other words, the OP's code doesn't have a base case. For every possible value of the integer `I` the template will still instantiate itself, so it will recurse forever (assuming there is an infinite amount of computing resources of course).