# Functional "simultanity"?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

*At this [link](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=450922), functional programming is spoken of. Specifically, the author says this:*

Simultaneity means that we assume a statement in lambda calculus is evaluated all at once. The trivial function:

```
λf(x) ::= x f(x)
```

defines an infinite sequence of whatever you plug in for x. The stepwise expansion looks like this:

```
0   - f(x)
1   - x f(x)
2   - x x f(x)
3   - x x x f(x)
```

The point is that we have to assume that the 'f()' and 'x' in step three million have the same meaning they did in step one.

At this point, those of you who know something about FP are muttering "referential transparency" under your collective breath. I know. I'll beat up on that in a minute. For now, just suspend your disbelief enough to admit that the constraint does exist, and the aardvark won't get hurt.

The problem with infinite expansions in a real-world computer is that.. well.. they're infinite. As in, "infinite loop" infinite. You can't evaluate every term of an infinite sequence before moving on to the next evaluation unless you're planning to take a really long coffee break while you wait for the answers.

Fortunately, theoretical logic comes to the rescue and tells us that preorder evaluation will always give us the same results as postorder evaluation.

More vocabulary.. need another function for this.. fortunately, it's a simple one:

```
λg(x) ::= x x
```

Now.. when we make the statement:

```
g(f(x))
```

Preorder evaluation says we have to expand f(x) completely before plugging it into g(). But that takes forever, which is.. inconvenient. Postorder evaluation says we can do this:

```
0   - g(f(x))
1   - f(x) f(x)
2   - x f(x) x f(x)
3   - x x f(x) x x f(x)
```

*. . . could someone explain to me what is meant here? I haven't a clue what's being said. Maybe point me to a really good FP primer that would get me started.*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange

Comment: Since lambda calculus doesn't have side effects you can start expanding wherever you'd like so he just kept `f(x)` and expanded `g` first to `f(x) f(x)`. Then he started expanding both pf them a couple of times to et the feeling of twice infinite expansions of `f`.

Comment: That's a whole lot of incoherent (to me) rambling just to say "functional programming is not lambda calculus". Well, duh. The rest of the article relies mostly on the ambiguous nature of English (and on Perl) to "dispel" other "myths".

Comment: I agree, it's a pretty awful article. And if "simultaneity" actually was a thing in FP, then we'd probably have heard about it before, from more authoritative sources.

Comment: Can anyone explain what he's saying with the whole λf(x) ::= x f(x) and λg(x) ::= x x thing?

Comment: @user97954 That notation is very unorthodox (and apparently a bit inconsistent), but it looks like he's defining `f(x)` to be a function takes a function `x` and applies that function to `f(x)`. I don't know Perl, so I'm not sure whether or not this is actually Perl code though. I would have written it `f(x) := x(f(x))` or `f := λx. x (f x)` and `g := λx. x x`. I agree that this article doesn't look like a good resource for learning about FP.

Answer (score 1):

*(Warning, this answer is very long-winded. I thought it best to include general knowledge of lambda calculus because it is near impossible to find good explanations of it)*

The author appears to be using the syntax  `λg(x)` to mean a *named* function, rather than a traditional function in lambda calculus. The author also appears to be going on at length about how lambda calculus is not functional programming in the same way that a Turing machine isn't imperative programming. There's practicalities and ideals that exist with those abstractions that aren't present in the programming languages frequently used to represent them. But before getting into that, a primer on lambda calculus may help. In lambda calculus, all functions look like this:

```
λarg.body
```

That's it. There's a `λ` symbol (called "lambda", hence the name) followed by a *named argument* and only *one* named argument, then followed by a period, then followed by an expression that represents the body of the function. For instance, the `identity` function which takes anything and just returns it right back would look like this:

```
λx.x
```

And *evaluating an expression* is just a series of simple rules for swapping out functions and arguments with their body expressions. An expression has the form:

```
function-or-expression arg-or-expression
```

Reducing it usually has the rules "If the left thing is an expression, reduce it. Otherwise, it must be a function, so use `arg-or-expression` as the argument to the function, and replace this expression with the `body` of the function. It is very important to note that there is *no requirement* that the `arg-or-expression` be reduced *before* being used as an argument. That is, both of the following are equivalent and mathematically identical reductions of the expression `λx.x (λy.y 0)` (assuming you have some sort of definition for 0, because lambda calculus requires you define numbers as functions):

```
λx.x (λy.y 0)
=> λx.x 0
=> 0

λx.x (λy.y 0)
=> λy.y 0
=> 0
```

In the first reduction, the *argument* was reduced *before* being used in the `λx.x` function. In the second, the argument was merely *substituted* into the `λx.x` function body - it wasn't reduced before being used. When this concept is used in programming, it's called "lazy evaluation" - you don't actually evaluate (reduce) an expression until you need to. What's important to note is that in lambda calculus, *it does not matter whether an argument is reduced or not before substitution*. The mathematics of lambda calculus **prove** that you'll get the same result either way as long as both terminate. This is definitely not the case in programming languages, because all sorts of things (usually relating to a change in the program's state) can make lazy evaluation different from normal evaluation.

Lambda calculus needs some extensions to be useful however. There's no way to name things. Suppose we allowed that though. In particular, let's create our own definition of what a function looks like in lambda calculus:

```
λname(arg).body
```

We'll say this means that the function `λarg.body` is *bound* to `name`, and anywhere else in any accompanying lambda expressions we can replace `name` with `λarg.body`. So we could do this:

```
λidentity(x).x
```

And now when we write `identity`, we'll just replace it with `λx.x`. This introduces a problem however. What happens if a named function *refers to itself?*

```
λevil(x).(evil x)
```

Now we've got a problem. According to our rule, we should be able to replace the `evil` in the `body` with what the name is bound to. But since the name is bound to `λx.(evil x)`, as soon as we try:

```
λevil(x).(evil x)
=> λevil(x).(λx.(evil x) x)
=> λevil(x).(λx.(λx.(evil x) x) x)
=> ...
```

We get an infinite loop. We can *never* evaluate this expression, because we have *no way of turning it from our special named lambda form to a regular lambda expression*. We can't go from the language with our special extension down to regular lambda calculus because we can't satisfy the rule of "replace `evil` with the function expression `evil` is bound to". There are some tricks for dealing with this, but we'll get to that in a minute.

An important point here is that this is *completely* different from a regular lambda calculus program that evaluates infinitely and never finishes. For instance, consider the *self application function* which takes something and applies it to itself:

```
λx.(x x)
```

If we evaluate this with the `identity` function, we get:

```
λx.(x x) λx.x
=> λx.x λx.x
=> λx.x
```

Using named functions and naming this function `self`:

```
self identity
=> identity identity
=> identity
```

But what happens if we pass `self` to *itself?*

```
λx.(x x) λx.(x x)
=> λx.(x x) λx.(x x)
=> λx.(x x) λx.(x x)
=> ...
```

We get an expression that loops into repeatedly reducing `self self` into `self self` over and over again. This is a plain old infinite loop you'd find in any (Turing-complete) programming language.

The difference between this and our problem with recursive definitions is that our names and definitions *are not lambda calculus*. They are *shorthands* which we can *expand* to lambda calculus by following some rules. But in the case of `λevil(x).(evil x)`, we can't expand it to lambda calculus so we don't even get a lambda calculus expression to run. Our named function "fails to compile" in a sense, similar to when you send the programming language *compiler* into an infinite loop and your code never even starts as opposed to when the actual *runtime* loops. (Yes, it is [entirely possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079603/infinite-compilation-with-templates) to make the compiler get caught in an infinite loop.)

There are some very clever ways to get around this problem, one of which is the infamous [Y-combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator). The basic idea is you take our problematic `evil` function and change it to instead of accepting an argument and trying to be recursive, accepts an argument and *returns another function that accepts an argument*, so your `body` expression has two arguments to work with:

```
λevil(f).λy.(f y)
```

If we evaluate `evil identity`, we'll get a new function that takes an argument and just calls `identity` with it. The following evaluation shows first the name replacement using ->, then the reduction using =>:

```
(evil identity) 0
-> (λf.λy.(f y) identity) 0
-> (λf.λy.(f y) λx.x) 0
=> λy.(λx.x y) 0
=> λx.x 0
=> 0
```

Where things get *interesting* is if we pass `evil` to itself instead of `identity`:

```
(evil evil) 0
-> (λf.λy.(f y) λf.λy.(f y)) 0
=> λy.(λf.λy.(f y) y) 0
=> λf.λy.(f y) 0
=> λy.(0 y)
```

We ended up with a function that's complete nonsense, but we achieved something important - *we created one level of recursion*. If we were to evaluate `(evil (evil evil))`, we would get two levels. With `(evil (evil (evil evil)))`, three. So what we need to do is instead of passing `evil` to itself, we need to pass a function that somehow accomplishes this recursion for us. In particular, it should be a function with some sort of self application. What we want is the Y-combinator:

```
λf.(λx.(f (x x)) λx.(f (x x)))
```

This function is pretty tricky to wrap your head around from the definition, so it's best to just call it `Y` and see what happens when we try and evaluate a few things with it:

```
Y evil
-> λf.(λx.(f (x x)) λx.(f (x x))) evil
=> λx.(evil (x x)) λx.(evil (x x))
=> evil (λx.(evil (x x))
         λx.(evil (x x)))
=> evil (evil (λx.(evil (x x))
               λx.(evil (x x))))
=> evil (evil (evil (λx.(evil (x x))
                     λx.(evil (x x)))))
```

And as we can see, this goes on infinitely. What we've done is taken `evil`, which accepts first one function and *then* accepts an argument and evaluates that argument using the function, and passed it a specially modified version of the `evil` function which expands to provide recursion. So we can create a "recursion point" in the `evil` function by reducing `evil (Y evil)`. So now, whenever we see a named function using recursion like this:

```
λname(x).(.... some body containing (name arg) in it somewhere)
```

We can transform it to:

```
λname-rec(f).λx.(...... body with (name arg) replaced with (f arg))
λname(x).((name-rec (Y name-rec)) x)
```

We turn the function into a version that first accepts a function to use as a recursion point, then we provide the function `Y name-rec` as the function to use as the recursion point.

The reason this works, and getting waaaaay back to the original point of the author, is because the expression `name-rec (Y name-rec)` *does not have to fully reduce `Y name-rec` before starting its own reduction*. I cannot stress this enough. We've already seen that reducing `Y name-rec` results in an infinite loop, so the recursion works if there's some sort of *condition* in the `name-rec` function that means that the next step of `Y name-rec` might not need to be reduced.

This breaks down in many programming languages, including functional ones, because they do not support this kind of lazy evaluation. Additionally, almost *all* programming languages support *mutation*. That is, if you define a variable `x = 3`, later in the same code you can make `x = 5` and all the old code that referred to `x` when it was 3 will now see `x` as being 5. This means your program could have completely different results if that old code is "delayed" with lazy evaluation and only calculated later on, because by then `x` could be 5. In a language where things can be arbitrarily executed in any order at any time, you have to completely eliminate your program's dependency on things like order of statements and time-changing values. If you don't, your program could calculate arbitrarily different results depending on what order your code gets run in.

However, writing code that has no sense of order in it whatsoever is *extremely* difficult. We saw how complicated lambda calculus got just trying to get our heads around trivial recursion. Therefore, most functional programming languages pick a model that systematically defines in what order things are evaluated in, and they never deviate from that model.

Racket, a dialect of Scheme, specifies that in the normal Racket language, all expressions are evaluated "eagerly" (no delaying) and all function arguments are evaluated eagerly from left to right, *but* the Racket program includes special forms that let you selectively make certain expressions lazy, such as `(promise ...)`. Haskell does the opposite, with expressions *defaulting* to lazy evaluation and having the compiler run a "strictness analyser" to determine which expressions are needed by functions that are specially declared to need arguments to be eagerly evaluated.

The primary point being made seems to be that it's just too impractical to design a language that completely allows all expressions to be individually lazy or eager, because the limitations this poses on what tools you can use in the language are severe. Therefore, it's important to keep in mind what tools a functional language provides you for manipulating lazy expressions and eager expressions, because they are most certainly not equivalent in all practical functional programming languages.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in the part that says the stuff like `λx.(x x)` isn't actually lambda calculus and that it's a shorthand for it (other than a couple missing parentheses). It follows all the rules of lambda calculus (and so do the β-reductions of the expressions that you've provided) and they are well-formed (or they would be with a few more parentheses). There is no notion of "compilation" of a lambda expression, there is only λ-abstraction, α-conversion, η-conversion and β-reduction which would correspond to an evaluation of a (untyped) lambda calculus expression.

Comment: I don't think I said that `λx.(x x)` wasn't lambda calculus, what I was trying to say was that the shorthand for the _named_ versions of the functions wasn't lambda calculus. It was an extension that could be replaced by equivalent lambda calculus expressions (hence the "compilation" analogy), but in some circumstances this replacement rule led to an infinite loop. That was the case with the naive recursion attempt `evil` using the extension. `λx.(x x)` is lambda calculus, `λself(x).(x x)` _isn't_, it's a shorthand that must first be translated to equivalent lambda calculus.