# Why do all C++ compilers crash or hang from this code?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17

The following bit of code crashes or hangs until memory exhaustion when compiled by every C++ compiler I've tested:

```
#include <tuple>

template<class... Ts>
auto f(Ts... ts){
  return f(std::make_tuple(ts...)); 
}

auto a = f();
```

Tested on various versions of GCC, Clang, MSVC, icc, ELLCC: https://godbolt.org/z/cwqiZK

---

My question is why is this not caught by template depth limits or similar safeties that these compilers implement? I found some examples of code, [like this old example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6079626), that cause compilers to hang, but it seems like all of the issues I could find have been fixed since it became standard to limit template instantiation depth.

I should note that this is not unique to `make_tuple`, and works for `tie`, `forward_as_tuple`... etc.

---

As a warning, if you try to compile this locally, be sure to use something like `ulimit` to make sure the compiler does not exhaust your memory. I had to hard reboot a couple of times while playing around with this.

Comment: They do have depth limits, but in this case the memory required probably grows quadratically with the depth, since you will have std::tuple<std::tuple<...>> (N layers) at the Nth level.

Comment: *" if you try to compile this locally, be sure to use something like ulimit"* Or use (gcc) flag `-ftemplate-depth=X` manually [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f75914c384b309fb).

Comment: @Brian, this seems to be correct! Limiting template depth to values around 100 resolves it

Comment: BTW, resulting program would be UB (empty infinite loop).

Comment: This is kind of asking like why don't compilers solve the halting problem.

Comment: @Jarod42: This is weird, given that my gcc manpage (Debian) says that `ftemplate-depth` is about template classes, not functions. Quote: `Set the maximum instantiation depth for template classes to n.`

Comment: @Barry, is it, though? In this case, there is plenty of information provided to know a halt is impossible.

Comment: @JeffreyCash: "*is it, though?*" Yes, it is. There are many cases where you can determine if a halt is possible in many languages, but that doesn't mean the compiler should attempt to do so. Just because you can see that there is infinite recursion does not mean we should make the *compiler* attempt to do the same.

Comment: You are observing effects of undefined behavior caused by the infinite recursive instantiations. There is an implementation-defined limit.

Comment: @user3684240: Didn't know that, but as pointed by Brian, there is also (recursive) `std::tuple` involved.

Answer (score 1):

GCC doesn't implement all possible variadic function template recursion detection methods (or possibly not any?), probably due to a variation of the concerns raised in the comments.

The OP example looks very similar (identical?) to [GCC bug 59914](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59914) from 2014 that is unresolved. It looks like preventing these kinds of mistakes, or actually - preventing these kinds of mistakes from exploding all over a developer's workstation - is not a high priority for GCC developers. BTW - the example program reported in the bug abuses memory much faster than the OP: with an 800MB data limit, I can get the OP to do more than 150 template instantiations while the program in the bug report runs out of memory after less than 20.

Both programs also crash clang, so I guess the clang devs have similar priorities.